# show same picture after reload (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I need help with a code that will make images of lunch of the day will rotate every day, I have found the code, and it works for me, but every time I refresh the page, the list return to the picture 1, instead of being on picture 4 as it was before updating the page. I know I have to use local storage, can someone show me how I can use it?

```
    jQuery.jQueryRandom = 0;
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[":"],
    {
        random: function(a, i, m, r) {
            if (i == 0) {

            };
            return i == jQuery.jQueryRandom;
        }
    });        

    $(function() {
      $('#slideshow img').not(':random').hide(); //hide all images except one initially
      setInterval(function(){
        $('#slideshow img:visible').fadeOut('fast')
          .siblings('img:random').fadeIn('slow')
           .end().appendTo('#slideshow');}, 
        86400); // 24 h (sekunder) intervall

    $(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage && localStorage.getItem('activeComm')){
    comm=localStorage.getItem('activeComm');
    $('#'+comm).slideToggle("fast");
}
$(".hide").click(function(){
   $comm=$(this).next(".comm");
   $comm.slideToggle("fast");
   localStorage.setItem('activeComm',$comm.attr('id'));
   return false;
});


</script></i>
```

Comment: Please try to format your code properly. It seems to be missing braces. Also `$(function(){})` and `$(document).ready` are the same thing. Doesn't make sense nesting one inside the other. Finally you really need to get used to using `var` and not making all your variables global. This can lead to hidden bugs that are very difficult to trace

Comment: You should provide the whole code, including HTML, not just Javascript